# import db in phpmyadmin and comments

Tags: database, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to move one site to another hosting and faced one problem with import DB in phpmyadmin. This DB has alot of functions and procedures which wrapped in /* */. As I understand, this is a comment section and it will be no difference if I just remove them. But why is phpmyadmin search errors in this comment sections? Or this is not a comment sections when it goes to a database?

Thanks

Comment: Which error do you get when importing?

Comment: #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

I thought it shows because of this 

/*!50020 DEFINER=`user`@`db`*/

, so I removed all this lines, but then another error appears, something about bad syntax. Anyway problem solved already, had to ask hosting support to fix my problem. They said my db dump was really bad.